# Domain model for money transactions

Tags: model, currency, domain-model, banking

I must develop a domain model for money transactions. So far I've figured out that every user  (money account) has attribute "amount" which defines how much money he has and then transaction between accounts are in the Transaction class which holds user1.id, user2.id and amount transfered.

Now I'm curious how to use that model to show when the user makes a transaction from a credit card onto the account. There's no "from" with that transaction. Should I just leave the field empty?

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, the credit card is its own "account", with its own balance (normally negative; the CC holder is in debt to the card issuer) and pretty much everything else you'd have on a bank account. I would follow that convention.